# Validating user input in a textbox in Winforms with values in the database

Tags: vb.net, winforms, validation

I have a windows form page with a textbox. The user needs to enter a "Code" into the textbox and upon a button click a validation should be done. Upon validating that this code exists in the database table a new page should be loaded which will contain details associated with this particular code like the year it was added, the document name, file path etc.

This is my first time programming in VB and I am not entirely familiar with the validation process and how the validation should be done against the database (I am using SQL Server).This is what I have until now:

```
    Private Sub EnterClick_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EnterClick.Click
    Dim oRij As New NICOCrypt.Rijndael
    Dim cnn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(oRij.NICO_RijndaelManaged_Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectionString")))
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim oFiles As SqlClient.SqlParameter
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    Dim valueExistsInDB As Boolean = CBool(CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0)
    cnn.Close()

    If valueExistsInDB = True AndAlso txtCode.Text IsNot Nothing Then

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If the code must exist, why not put the code list in a combo and let them pick.  no validation required

Comment: Even if I avoid the validation I still have to populate the fields associated with that particular code from the database in the next screen. So would it be difficult to check the code in the database and pull the associated details with it into the next dialog box on button click?

Comment: Thats a different question, but not difficult.  Load the data into a DataTable.  Show (DisplayMember) the code.  When they pick, all the other data will be  already there and available in the DataRow associated with that code.

Comment: Not for nothing, but you have asked 10 previous questions and gotten 7 answers but only ever accepted one (1).  Accepting answers and upvoting posts which help you helps others find good answers.  If you are not in a position to answer questions, you can still help by accepting and (soon) upvoting helpful posts.  The [Tour] explains how SO works

Comment: sure, thank you for the suggestion. I will make sure to do that from now :)